# how to override settings file foundation

Tags: html, css, overriding, zurb-foundation

I want to create custom icon-bar, I read that I need to create "_icon-bar.scss" file and include this code inside:

```
@import "foundation/components/icon-bar";
$include-html-icon-bar-classes: $include-html-classes

// We use these to style the icon-bar and items

$include-html-icon-bar-classes: $include-html-classes

// We use these to style the icon-bar and items
$icon-bar-bg: $oil;
$icon-bar-font-color: $white;
$icon-bar-font-color-hover: $icon-bar-font-color;
$icon-bar-font-size: 1rem;
$icon-bar-hover-color: $primary-color;
$icon-bar-icon-color: $white;
$icon-bar-icon-color-hover: $icon-bar-icon-color;
$icon-bar-icon-size: 1.875rem;
$icon-bar-image-width: 1.875rem;
$icon-bar-image-height: 1.875rem;
$icon-bar-active-color: $primary-color;
$icon-bar-item-padding: 1.25rem;
$icon-bar-disabled-opacity: 0.7




.my-custom-class {
@include icon-bar(

  // Set the background color of the icon bar. Default: $icon-bar-bg.
  $bar-bg: $icon-bar-bg,
  //  Set the font color of the icon bar. Default: $icon-bar-font-color.
  $bar-font-color: $icon-bar-font-color,
  // Set the hover background color for the icon bar. Default: $icon-bar-hover-color.
  $bar-hover-color,
  // Set the color of the icons for the icon bar. Default: $icon-bar-icon-color
  $bar-icon-color: $icon-bar-icon-color,
  // Set the background of the color when the icon bar is clicked or tapped on (or items within the icon bar). Default: $icon-bar-active-color.
  $bar-active-color,
  // Set the padding for icon bar. Default: $icon-bar-item-padding.
  $padding,
  // Set the font-size of the icon bar. Default: $icon-bar-font-size.
  $font-size,
  // Set the size of the icons within the icon bar. Default: $icon-bar-icon-size.
  $icon-size,
  // Set the width of images within the icon bar. Default: $icon-bar-image-width
  $image-width,
  // Set the height of images within the icon bar. Default: $icon-bar-image-height
  $image-height,
  // Assign whether or not base styles usually associated with the icon bar to appear the way it usually does should be included. Default: true.
  $base-style: true,
  // Allow disabled icons. Default: false.
  // If enabled add class disabled.
  $disabled: false
  );
}
```

this code is simple code to override the foundation icon-bar.

This is the app.scss file:

```
@import "settings";
//@import "foundation"; 
@import "_icon-bar";

// Or selectively include components
// @import
//   "foundation/components/accordion",
//   "foundation/components/alert-boxes",
//   "foundation/components/block-grid",
//   "foundation/components/breadcrumbs",
//   "foundation/components/button-groups",
//   "foundation/components/buttons",
//   "foundation/components/clearing",
//   "foundation/components/dropdown",
//   "foundation/components/dropdown-buttons",
//   "foundation/components/flex-video",
//   "foundation/components/forms",
//   "foundation/components/grid",
//   "foundation/components/inline-lists",
//   "foundation/components/joyride",
//   "foundation/components/keystrokes",
//   "foundation/components/labels",
//   "foundation/components/magellan",
//   "foundation/components/orbit",
//   "foundation/components/pagination",
//   "foundation/components/panels",
//   "foundation/components/pricing-tables",
//   "foundation/components/progress-bars",
//   "foundation/components/reveal",
//   "foundation/components/side-nav",
//   "foundation/components/split-buttons",
//   "foundation/components/sub-nav",
//   "foundation/components/switches",
//   "foundation/components/tables",
//@import "foundation/components/tabs",
//   "foundation/components/thumbs",
//   "foundation/components/tooltips",
// @import "foundation/components/top-bar",
//   "foundation/components/type",
//   "foundation/components/offcanvas",
//   "foundation/components/visibility";
```

Also I saw that I need to compile the compass before runing the program.
I tryed to run this code in cmd:
1. get in to my project folder ->  foundation-src
2. compass compile

after compile I get this error:

```
 error scss/app.scss (Line 7 of scss/_icon-bar.scss: Invalid CSS after "$icon
-bar-bg": expected selector or at-rule, was ": $oil;")
Compilation failed in 1 files.
```

I have tryed to delete this line in my "_icon-bar.scss" file, and I get the same error on the second line in this file,

what is wrong in my overriding?

Comment: Instead of @ import "_icon-bar"; you want @import "icon-bar"; (no underscore)

Comment: I did it but the error is still exist..

Comment: Do you have another idea?

Comment: Your error message is warning you that you need a semi-colon (;) after `$include-html-icon-bar-classes: $include-html-classes`. You also need one after `$icon-bar-disabled-opacity: 0.7`. I guess the second one isn't vital but is best practice. It also seems that you're commenting out the whole Foundation package? Without the core Foundation styles very little will behave as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `$include-html-icon-bar-classes: $include-html-classes` duplicated in your code? Seems like it's in the file twice...

```
$include-html-icon-bar-classes: $include-html-classes

// We use these to style the icon-bar and items

$include-html-icon-bar-classes: $include-html-classes
```

Comment: I remove the first line, but nothing, it's look like that the compiler cant compile the _settings fields that I trying to override... what can I do?